# Hunting for a book about the use of math in warfare.

Tags: reference-request, math-history

When I was younger I checked out a book from my school library that really captivated me. It chronicled weapons development, describing the math that makes the weapons operate, as well as giving a detailed account of its strategic use in warfare every other chapter. The book was very formulaic and followed weapons development chronologically, ending at the atomic bomb (I think at least). I wasn’t as passionate about reading as I am now so I hope to be able to finish it if anyone here knows the title of this book.

Thank you